# How to use Python/Webdriver to go through multiple URLs and take screenshots using loops?

Tags: webdriver, python

I want to use Python/Webdriver to run through many client websites (and subpages within those websites) and take screenshots of each page. Currently, I have this working, but all clients are in their own files. Each client has the same subpages, so scaling and adding/removing can become tedious. I want to combine all the files into one file since they all use the same pages, but different base URL (per client). For example, myfirsturl.com and mysecondurl.com both have a /subpage1, /subpage2, /subpage3, etc. I figured using some sort of loop and/or nested loop was the best way to do this, but I can't figure this out. I am brand new to automation so I have a very beginner knowledge and mentality, so please be gentle :). After each step, I want to take a screenshot and save it for manual review/validation.

So, in English, it would be:

1. Go to client1
2. Take/save screenshot
3. Go to client1/subpage1
4. Take/save screenshot
5. Go to client1/subpage2
6. Take/save screenshot
7. Go to client2
8. Take/save screenshot
9. Go to client2/subpage1
10. Take/save screenshot

and so on....

Then, after that is done in, say, Firefox, do it again in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Edit: I know how to take screenshots. My question is how can I do the above sequence with loops, taking a screenshot of each page.

Comment: Did you tried using google? In 5 seconds I found get_screenshot_as_file() method. See [API docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) and [FAQ](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-take-screenshot-of-the-current-window)

Comment: Yes, I have that already. My question is how can I combine all of the separate files I have into one file and use some loops to do all the work of going to page X, then the subpages of that, capturing a screenshot of each. My question was not how to actually capture a screenshot.

Comment: Rest is plain old programming and image processing.

Comment: Which is what I need the help with. As stated in my original question, I am brand new to automation so I have a very beginner knowledge and mentality. I'm trying to learn. I have everything working fine when each client is in its own file, so I'm not looking for handouts. I have that learning experience. However, I am having trouble creating one file where everything is done in that one file without any/a lot of code repetition (keeping an eye on scaling in the future). This is where I need help...in the logic and programming of getting it into one file. The way I have it now won't scale well.

Comment: IOW your question is in no way related to QA or webdriver. It is a plain programming question. You would get zillions of answers on stack exchange - or get downvoted as too trivial.

Comment: Wow, well it is a QA related function/duty and I am using Python and Webdriver, so I figured I would put it here...I don't understand why it wouldn't go here...and I don't understand why it matters that it is here. If you can't answer, then please don't continue to comment. It has been clear since your first comment that you had no help to provide. What I'm asking help with is a way to make my testing better, therefore it belongs in QA.

Comment: I am trying to suggest you place where you get better and faster answer. Feel free to ignore my advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use loops in a programming language and not about testing per-se.

Comment: Hey @python, welcome to SQA. I understand that it's hard to figure out where your question fits when you're just starting out, and SQA may feel like a more comfortable home for it. But really, the previous commenters are right - you'd be better off having a look at Stack Overflow, as once you remove the bits you've already got working, what remains is a pure programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's a low level question, but based on how I understand the question this would be my suggestion. I was a beginner once too and I remember how frustrating it can be.

```
# make a list for everything you want to loop over
browsers = [
    'chrome'
    ,'firefox'
    ]

client_urls = [
    'www.client1.com'
    ,'www.client2.com'
    ]

sub_pages = [
    '/subpage1'
    ,'/subpage2'
    ]

#create a list of all clients and pages
complete_urls = [client_url + sub_page for client_url in client_urls for sub_page in sub_pages] 

#check that list in each browser
for browser in browsers:
    #insert your code for creating a new webdriver for the given browser
    for complete_url in complete_urls:
        driver.get(complete_url)
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file()
```